# Make another screen not using Windows

Tags: c#, windows, screen

I have a tiny LED screen (Eurolite pixel mesh 64) of 64x48 pixels, `DVI`  connected to the 2nd output of my graphics card. Windows doesn't extend the desktop to a screen smaller than 800 x 600 pixels.

Do you know if it's possible to control the 2nd screen displaying displaying in `C#` without using Windows extending desktop functionality ?

I'm searching about calling directly a graphic driver or sending bytes to dedicated ouput video port but nothing found

Comment: Do such tiny screens exist with a DVI interface? Sounds like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. I am just asking in case 64x48 was a typo... You could probably even poll the 3kPixels in realtime with negligible cpu load... Maybe USB or SPI or something would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes it exists and i can't change port to Usb unfortunately ... it's to control an Eurolite Pixel Mesh 64 screen

Comment: Ah, so it's LED. So you probably don't want to use some bundled software but write your own, right?

Comment: yes I have a special need, the screen should not be detected by windows unlike bundled software. I update question

Comment: @GGO "special requirement" - "special needs" has quite different connotations.

Comment: @Fildor yes sorry special requirement if helps

Comment: You didn't put enough details, by looking at the docs there are multiple ways of communicating with such screen ...

Comment: @Aybe Have you really seen others ways ? In my docs there is an only DVI way. That's why i would like to control the output video dvi port. Doesn't matter what screen there is behind. I didn't see what i could detail more

Comment: It can be controlled over Ethernet as well: http://www.steinigke.de/fr/mpn80503110-eurolite-led-pixel-mesh-64x64.html

Comment: @Aybe Thanks but it will not works. Eurolite use Ethernet conectors to communicate between the scanning box and the screen panel, but it's not a standard IP protocol. They have their own : various voltage 0-10v and wires order change. Yes it too bad :/

Comment: So I guess all that's left to you would be to use their own application :(

Comment: No because scanning box is connected to the DVI port. I can display all i want, like a classical second screen. That's why i want to generate my own output video signal on 2nd DVI port